# Astronomy tags were not merged?

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags, migration

I see that Astronomy beta was merged into Physics, however, [many of my questions are now untagged](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

Is there some way we can get all the tags on Astronomy moved over to Physics and applied to the questions that were migrated?

Comment: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1235/how-should-we-go-about-retagging-the-salvaged-posts

Comment: This is strange, why did the questions from TP keep their tags and the questios from Astronomy lost them?

Comment: @Dilaton: Presumably the team concluded that the tagging from TP would transfer cleanly, but tat we might want to re-consider the Astro tagging.

Comment: I think the SE team needs to address this one... but we do aim to manually go through and retag all the questions anyway. You can help by putting the appropriate tags on your questions. (Note that the tags that are appropriate for it here may not exactly match the tags that were appropriate for it on Astronomy; in particular, there is a [list of subfield tags](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8/physics-subfield-tags-and-general-tag-rules) that every question should probably have at least one of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do this - the migration process *intentionally* strips tags that don't exist on the destination, to avoid polluting that site with tags that do not belong. In fact, questions currently marked [untagged](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) would normally *fail migration* without moderator intervention due to the lack of any tag overlap on the destination site!

As I've previously noted, all of these questions will need to be reviewed eventually - that's a huge job, but there's no way around it: for as much overlap as they might have had, Astronomy and Theoretical Physics were separate sites with separate cultures and styles; integrating those questions is key to avoiding confusion for future readers.

I've tried to make this a *little* easier though, by providing lists of all migrated questions *along with their original tags*. I highly suggest splitting these up into "bite-sized" tasks and tackling them one by one.

See: [Questions imported from Astronomy and Theoretical Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/questions-imported-from-astronomy-and-theoretical-physics/)