# Questions imported from Astronomy and Theoretical Physics

Tags: discussion, site-salvage, migration, retagging

In the answers below, you'll find links to all of the questions recently imported from Theoretical Physics and Astronomy, along with the tags they had on those sites.

Imported questions retain only the tags that already exist on the destination site. Tags that do not exist may not be appropriate - please review before re-adding. Other changes may also be necessary. Take your time...

The raw data can be found here:

**Astronomy exports (not just to Physics):** https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnuSKH8sLqgjdHBMRnZqQmNwRHNmVENmM3JNRVhZb1E#gid=0

**Theoretical Physics exports (not just to Physics):** https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnuSKH8sLqgjdGRKUWhPMzZKQVlVYmJ5WnQwdDU0NEE

Comment: wow, we have our work cut out for us... ;-)

Comment: As a regular on Astro.SE, can I happily start retagging these questions? Or will I be contravening unwritten community rules or something? I don't want to look like an Astro crashing the Physics party! :P

Comment: @Warrick: yes, but coordinate your efforts with others: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1235/how-should-we-go-about-retagging-the-salvaged-posts

Answer (score 1):

#### Astronomy imports: 1 of 5

The following posts were migrated here from Astronomy. The original tags are listed below each link.

<sup><sub>Split among 5 answers due to length</sub></sup>

```
Best periods to observe Magellanic Clouds?
   observation cloud
Do all black holes have a singularity?
   black-holes neutron-stars singularity
What does f/4.6 mean in a telescope and how important is this value?
   telescopes
What is the typical career path to become a professional Astronomer?
   education career 
Lenses (refractor) or mirrors (reflector) telescope?
   telescopes reflector refractor
What is exactly a Dobsonian, and what are the differences when compared with Schmidt-Casse
   telescopes
Can the apparent equal size of sun and moon be explained or is this a coincidence?
   sun moon 
How can I judge a globular cluster on the Shapley & Sawyer scale?
   globular-clusters visual-astronomy classification 
Which is the strongest meteor shower expected in the next years in the Northern hemisphere
   meteor-showers 
For observing planets what kind of telescope offers the best view?
   visual-astronomy eyepieces reflector refractor planets
Why is M42 red in the pictures, but green when observed at the eyepiece?
   nebula photography
Why don't modern spacecraft use nuclear power?
   voyager spacecraft exploration satellite
How are Cepheids used to evaluate their distance?
   stars distance
What age to start kids with astronomy
   visual-astronomy amateur-astronomy
What is the current status of Pluto?
   planets pluto 
What are good resources for someone looking to become an amateur astronomer?
   amateur resources 
What objects look best in an O-III filter?
   visual-astronomy filters planetary-nebulae
Where can I find public domain astronomical pictures?
   nebula stars
A method to estimate the relative magnitude of a star using nearby stars
   magnitude
Observing lunar lander and footprints on the moon?
   telescopes the-moon aperture
Can we observe changes in the fine-structure constant?
   cosmology 
What causes millisecond pulsars to speed up?
   neutron-stars pulsars gamma-rays
How do the â€œhot Jupiterâ€ planets get so close to their host star?
   planets extrasolar-planets 
Why don't more rocky planets/moons have appreciable atmospheres?
   planets atmosphere moons mercury 
Scientific value of timing total lunar occultations
   observation the-moon 
What tools do I need to track an orbit of a mystery object?
   observation equipment
Why can we see the cosmic microwave background (CMB)?
   cosmology big-bang cmb
Why is Uranus's axis of rotation tilted?
   planets cosmology uranus orbit
What is Dark Energy, and how was it discovered?
   physics dark-energy
What is a backlit CCD sensor, and why might I prefer it to other kinds?
   astrophotography 
What is a spectrometer, and why are they so useful in science?
   instrument 
How important is a camera with improved Hydrogen Alpha sensitivity to astrophotography?
   astrophotography planetary-nebulae color
What are the pros and cons of a german equatorial mount vs. a fork mount?
   equipment 
What open-source n-body codes are available and what are their features?
   software simulation
Do all narrowband filters tint the field of view?
   filters observation color
Is there any evidence for the claim that the moon was once part of the Earth?
   earth the-moon
Why does each celestial object spin on its own axis?
   gravity spin rotation
Resources and requirements for amateur spectroscopy
   amateur resources spectroscopy
Does Earth have a code name?
   catalog
Who should I contact if I see an unknown object in the sky?
   unknown-object
Is it possible to see Fraunhofer lines with amateur equipment?
   equipment spectroscopy 
How does a spacecraft's orientation get determined
   spacecraft 
After the Space Shuttle is retired, how will the new sections of ISS will be launched?
   shuttle launch
How can a black hole emit X-rays?
   black-holes gravity
Scopes to avoid as a beginner?
   telescopes beginner advice
Why are orbits elliptical?
   orbit planetary-motion gravitation
When taking a sequence of exposures for stacking/coaddition, what dither patterns are most
   telescopes observation software
Optimal Angular Field of View (AFOV)
   telescopes eyepieces 
How to determine what size telescope to buy
   telescopes optics
What allows the modified Urca process to work at lower density than direct Urca in neutron
   astrophysics neutron-stars
Can any telescope be used for solar observing?
   telescopes sun solar
What are the prerequisites for considering any other planet to be habitable?
   planets planetary-habitability
When will the Moon reach escape velocity?
   earth the-moon
How to nail focus for DSLR astrophotography?
   astrophotography focus
Why does the moon sometimes appear giant and a orange red color near the horizon?
   moon
Ways of verifying the origin of a meteorite?
   meteorite the-moon 
Seeing cosmic activity now, really means it happens millions/billions of years ago ?
   distance time light-years
What criteria were used to set the "useme" flag in the NOMAD astrometric catalog?
   astrometry catalog 
What size aperature would I need to find and see the supernova in M51?
   visual-astronomy amateur aperture supernova 
How dark does it have to be to see the gegenschein?
   dust 
Is the length of the day increasing?
   earth sun
How can a spiral galaxy exist?
   astrophysics galaxy
Are there websites or programmes that permit a simulation of the night sky in the past and
   software constellations
Is there a good explanation for the observation of Martian canals?
   mars water
How can the Earth's day increase and its rotation slow down at the same time?
   earth rotation 
What makes a good set of binoculars?
   equipment 
Observing Jupiter's non-Galilean moons
   telescopes moons jupiter solar-system
How many stars are in the Milky Way galaxy, and how can we determine this?
   galaxies milky-way
Why are there more lunar maria on the near side than on the far side?
   the-moon
What is the probability that a star of a given spectral type will have planets?
   planets exoplanets
Collision of charged black holes
   black-holes 
What to cite for MSX6 survey?
   resources
How do you respond to questions like "Have you ever observed a UFO?"
   observation spacecraft unknown-object 
What is meant when it is said that the universe is homogeneous and isotropic?
   cosmology universe
How large is the universe?
   cosmology big-bang special-relativity light universal-expansion
What kind of telecommunication systems do astronauts use in space?
   astronaut 
What's the best way to watch meteor showers?
   meteor-showers 
The most distant point from the earth that a space shuttle could reach till now
   distance shuttle space-flight
In what ways can a lunar eclipse occur?
   the-moon eclipse
How do air cherenkov telescopes work?
   gamma-rays telescopes instruments
How does atmospheric seeing evolve over time?
   observation seeing weather
What are the various kinds of Cassegrain telescopes, and what benefits and drawbacks does 
   optics telescopes
Why is the Ritcheyâ€“ChrÃ©tien telescope preferred in professional astronomy?
   optics telescopes professional-astronomy
Smaller free remote control telescopes?
   telescopes
What is the name of our Galaxy?
   galaxy
What is a decent beginner's camera for astrophotography?
   astrophotography
What is an asterism compared to a constellation?
   constellations
What does the sky look like to human eyes from orbit?
   visual-astronomy orbit
Binary stars' apparent magnitude
   stars apparent-magnitude
What's dark matter and who discovered it?
   cosmology astrophysics galaxies dark-matter
What latitude is needed before you can reliably see Omega Centauri?
   visual-astronomy globular-clusters 
How to convert a FITS file to .xls Excel file?
   astrophotography fits-files
What is the most distant object from the Earth that a spacecraft has visited to date?
   spacecraft space-flight nasa
How does a comet form?
   comet
How do you clean a dusty lens?
   telescopes equipment
Mixing and matching across eyepiece designs / manufacturers?
   equipment amateur eyepieces
Are solar physics images of use to the night-time community?
   solar-telescopes
Are the Voyager probes still sending us a signal ?
   voyager
How are newly discovered objects (stars, planets, galaxies...) named?
   professional-astronomy names 
Christoffel symbols and affine connection
   cosmology
What happen when two galaxies collide?
   galaxies
How do astronomers measure the distance to a star or other celestial object?
   distance stars
Shapes of galaxies
   galaxies
What frame(s) of reference are used to measure the rotation of the Sun around the galaxy ?
   sun rotation galaxy milky-way
How many earth-sized planets have been discovered outside the solar system?
   extrasolar-planets
Mirror lenses and DSLR astrophotography
   astrophotography
How to create unusual sundial?
   equipment sun physics time
Why can't you see meteors, but you can see comets from the moon?
   the-moon comet meteorite
Cameras in Voyager probes
   voyager
Why do astronomers say that there is not enough matter in Universe?
   cosmology astrophysics 
What do the colors in false color images represent?
   astrophotography light
How would two equally massed stars orbit?
   astrophysics orbit stars
Does the Moon's core still contain significant heat?
   the-moon
How would the night sky appear at the edge of the galaxy?
   visual-astronomy theory
Recommend good book(s) about the "scientific method" as it relates to astronomy/astrophysi
   astrophysics resources
What possible science could we do during the 2012 Venus transit?
   citizen-science
Why does a black hole have a finite mass?
   black-holes singularity
What did relativity clarify about Mercury?
   mercury relativity celestial-mechanics
Where to find Lunar Eclipse data
   the-moon eclipse
Could the earth have another moon?
   orbit moons
Can a moon have another large body as a satellite, and are there any examples of such?
   orbit moons celestial-mechanics
Is a rogue 'exoplanet' classed as a exoplanet?
   exoplanets
Significance of letters in Hertzsprung-Russell (H-R) diagram
   stars 
Why is a new moon not the same as a solar eclipse?
   moon eclipse solar
How do I use this 'Horizon Observatory'?
   observation visual-astronomy
Refraction and scattered light for NLCs
   atmosphere 
Why did the june 2011 lunar eclipse last so long?
   the-moon eclipse
How long would it take to scan the visible universe for unique signals?
   telescopes universe
How do we determine the mass of a black hole?
   black-holes
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Astronomy imports: 2 of 5

The following posts were migrated here from Astronomy. The original tags are listed below each link.

<sup><sub>Split among 5 answers due to length</sub></sup>

```
What if our Sun were located in the middle of a globular cluster?
   globular-clusters
How could I translate a field of view value into a magnification value?
   equipment software stellarium
Why don't we have a better telescope than the Hubble Space Telescope?
   telescopes
Planets capable of life: dead or still alive?
   planets exoplanets astrobiology
Two planets in same orbit - not planets?
   planets orbit
What would happen if the polar ice caps of Mars melted?
   mars speculative
Could two colliding comets near Earth cause devastation?
   comet speculative impact
Sillicon based life
   planetary-habitability astrobiology
What was the apparent magnitude of the June 15th 2011 lunar eclipse?
   the-moon eclipse apparent-magnitude
Is it possible to make a hydrogen-alpha solar scope?
   solar-telescopes 
Why are binary objects so critical to astronomy?
   binary-systems
Impact of gravity on bone structure
   gravity astrobiology
Has everything we see happened in the past?
   time light
Color Variation in RR Lyrae
   stars color
What is a "Trojan Moon"?
   moon
What does a planet look like in the infrared?
   planets infrared
Could dark energy be the effect of gravity at great distances?
   astrophysics amateur gravity dark-energy dark-matter
Study of exoplanets reaching saturation point
   exoplanets
Space Interferometry Mission (SIM) cancellation
   exoplanets
Lack of exoplanet missions in the decadal survey
   exoplanets
How would you describe a black hole to a complete layman?
   black-holes 
How to find the Andromeda galaxy without using a go-to telescope?
   observation galaxies
How exactly does time slow down near a black hole?
   black-holes gravity time theory
Why is the universe map shaped like an oval?
   cosmology
Why is the universe so big?
   cosmology universe
Advice sought on choosing a camera for a Meade LX10
   telescopes astrophotography
What happens to light and mass in the center of a black hole?
   black-holes gravity
What is the simplest way to prove the Earth is round?
   earth solar solar-system education
What is the simplest way to prove that the Earth orbits the Sun?
   education solar-system
Why is the surface of Venus so hot?
   planets
How can one predict the length of the Synodic month? Why is it irregular?
   moon the-moon time
What is the official difference between a planet and a dwarf planet?
   planets
Is there a consensus on the fate of our universe?
   universe big-bang universal-expansion 
Given that matter cannot escape a black hole, how did the big bang produce the universe we
   big-bang universal-expansion
What are the easiest ways to get data out of a FITS file without a library?
   fits-files
Do days and months on the Moon have names?
   the-moon rotation
What examples are there of fuzzy concepts in astronomy?
   theory
Mass of a galaxy via luminosity
   galaxies
Why is there still radiation left from the Big Bang now?
   big-bang cmb
Is there evidence of a larger universe?
   universe universal-expansion
Standards for scientific metadata in common-use image formats?
   astrophotography
Curiosity Rover (MSL): specification / dimensions
   mars 
What is Hawking radiation and how does it cause a black hole to evaporate?
   black-holes quantum-mechanics
How can a Population III star be so massive?
   stars
What is the strongest evidence that anti-matter exists?
   astrophysics anti-matter
Given a photo of the Moon, taken from Earth, is it possible to calculate the position of t
   astrophotography the-moon astrometry
Stellar Viscosity in Galaxies
   galaxies
Applying the Maxwellâ€“Boltzmann statistics to astrophysical objects
   universe
Seeking Recommendation for Celestron Firstscope Eyepiece Upgrade
   eyepieces telescopes beginner
What is the average distance between objects in our asteroid belt?
   distance solar-system asteroid
Is the "Great Attractor" an indicator of the "Multiverse"?
   cosmology gravity string-theory
What effects will the heliosheath have on the Voyager spacecraft?
   spacecraft voyager
Solar system, visible stars and deep sky objects
   galaxies stars milky-way
Can black holes actually merge?
   black-holes time
Why did the ancients fail to discover that the Earth orbits the Sun?
   planetary-motion
Can Vesta dominate the orbits of other asteroids?
   gravity orbit asteroid 
How dense are nebulae?
   nebula
Exoplanet detection via space-based parasol
   telescopes exoplanets stars satellite
Cosmic background radiation vs superfluids
   quantum-mechanics
If I shine a bright light on a neutron star, what would it look like?
   neutron-stars
Is the Milky Way significantly easier to see by astronauts?
   milky-way
Are there any practical applications of the uncertainty principle
   quantum-mechanics
Can the Hubble telescope bring any star into focus?
   telescopes visual-astronomy stars
Temperature of WIMPs
   cosmology astrophysics dark-matter
Universe Expansion
   universe universal-expansion
Spectral energy distribution fitting tools or routines
   software magnitude
Is there evidence of dark matter in our galaxy?
   astrophysics milky-way dark-matter
What is the cosmic "Axis of Evil" problem?
   cosmology cmb large-scale-structure
Equation for calculating the Sun's position 
   sun
How would we tell antimatter galaxies apart?
   astrophysics big-bang anti-matter
Do nearby gamma ray busts/supernova damage more than just the ozone layer?
   gamma-rays supernova 
What keeps galaxies united like a solar system?
   galaxies milky-way
Why is the universe so organized?
   planets galaxies universe stars celestial-mechanics
Metal Dilemma: Only very few civilizations per galaxy
   extrasolar-planets spectroscopy speculative
Does the current light pollution set a fundamental limit for the range of Earth-based tele
   telescopes visual-astronomy physics disturbing-factor 
Which current big Earth-based telescopes are equipped with adaptive optics?
   telescopes atmosphere seeing limits disturbing-factor
How does the central peak in moon craters form?
   the-moon 
What is so special about iron?
   astrophysics 
How are new nebulae being created?
   stars nebula star-formation
Would it be interesting or useful to map objects' current (predicted) locations?
   distance astrometry
"Blue Bumper" Stars
   variable-star
Relationship between the cosmic microwave background (CMB) radiation and the visible unive
   cmb
Is Jupiter a failed star?
   stars solar-system jupiter brown-dwarf
What will the universe look like for anyone falling into a black hole?
   black-holes
Has a human ever perished outside Earth's orbit?
   exploration astronaut
What's the difference between a red giant and a red supergiant?
   stars
What is the largest observed celestial body?
   black-holes stars
Why aren't space probes like New Horizons sped up in space?
   spacecraft
Could many widely separated space telescopes be combined for VLBI on IR/visible wavelength
   telescopes
Is there a method to estimate the atomic yield of a supernova of a given size?
   theory supernova
Names, maps for Milky Way dust clouds?
   milky-way dust
Can the Hanbury-Brown and Twiss effect be used to measure the size of composite objects li
   galaxies light quantum-mechanics galaxy instrument
Are orbits interior to Jupiter's orbit less stable than orbits exterior to Jupiter's orbit
   solar-system
When the Sun goes red giant, will it "vaporize" away a significant fraction of Jupiter and
   solar-system
What is the most convenient rocket engine to use exclusively in space?
   space-flight
Could Jupiter's gravity destabilize Earth's artificial satellites over a long timescale?
   solar-system jupiter
Are we capable of discovering planets in the Andromeda galaxy?
   telescopes exoplanets 
Why did the asteroid belt between Mars and Jupiter form as it did?
   solar-system asteroid
Are there formulae for calculating stellar luminosity and effective temperature as a funct
   astrophysics stars
Which is the heaviest present day lifter (rocket)? And is it comparable to the Saturn V ro
   spacecraft space-flight
How fast will the sun become a red giant?
   sun time
At what temperature does water become a liquid on Mars? On the asteroids? And in a vacuum?
   solar-system solar
What does ionization of neutral Hydrogen have to do with "transparency"?
   cosmology galaxies spectroscopy
Vesta dwarf planet status
   asteroid
Maximum depth for bacteria on rogue planets
   astrobiology
Distribution of each element and molecule as a function of distance from the Sun and as a 
   solar-system
Where does a star's angular momentum go as its spin slows down?
   stars
Are the inner planets on planar orbits because there was more dust in the inner solar syst
   solar-system
Is there a program that can computationally fit spherical harmonic functions onto a datase
   untagged
Could asteroseismology have a significant potential to unravel the mechanisms of solar cyc
   stars
Did I see two Milky Ways next to each other?
   observation milky-way amateur
Funding opportunities for an independent researcher
   career 
Where do the bipolar jets of black holes come from?
   black-holes
Assuming that the Sun wouldn't evolve into a red giant, how long would the Earth's atmosph
   planets
When we want to figure out the long-term evolution of a planet's atmosphere/orbit, when is
   solar-system
Which citizen-science astrophysics and astronomy projects currently exist?
   citizen-science amateur-astronomy 
How long do your eyes need to adapt to darkness and reach full contrast?
   telescopes eyepieces eye-physiology 
What was the most distant supernova spotted by a amateur astronomer until today?
   amateur-astronomy limits 
What is an approximation of the average number of supernovae every century in the Milky Wa
   milky-way supernova estimation approximation
Is the observable region of the universe within the event horizon of a super-massive black
   universe
How to identify the objects in an astrophoto, and what portion of the sky it covers?
   astrophotography software
Are there any known neutron stars just below the Tolmanâ€“Oppenheimerâ€“Volkoff limit?
   neutron-stars
Do stars of higher metallicity have more planets in highly-inclined Pluto-like orbits?
   solar-system
Could dark energy be linked to dark flow?
   gravity dark-energy
The orbit of 2010 TK7
   orbit asteroid
What free software is there for observing the sky (sky map software)
   software stellarium
How is the shape of the universe measured by scientists?
   universe
Next crescent moon?
   moon
What would a rotating black-hole look like to a "geo-stationary" observer orbiting the bla
   black-holes singularity
What exactly is the definition of motion and its relation to Mach's conjecture? 
   rotation special-relativity
When will Enceladus run out of water?
   moons
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Astronomy imports: 3 of 5

The following posts were migrated here from Astronomy. The original tags are listed below each link.

<sup><sub>Split among 5 answers due to length</sub></sup>

```
A Fermi-question: Are there more stars than grains of sand?
   universe calculations approximation 
What objects/states of objects with absolute magnitude do we know of?
   distance luminosity object 
Could the cosmic microwave background radiation (CMBR) map be used as a backup for GPS nav
   cmb
Vision vs. limiting magnitude
   observation visual-astronomy optics apparent-magnitude
Software for Creating Custom Star Charts?
   software 
Would the time dilation from being in low orbit around a black hole delay/slow the effects
   black-holes astrophysics
All significant objects in the universe?
   unknown-object object classification
Why is oxygen the third most abundant element?
   universe 
How did micrometeorite flux change with the age of the solar system?
   solar-system solar
Is CO2 really a potent greenhouse gas for planets around M dwarfs?
   atmosphere
How can we be sure that liquid iron/titanium droplets can form around particulates on hot 
   atmosphere
What is the mass of the LEGO figurines being launched with spacecraft Juno?
   jupiter nasa launch
How does the average Mars-Jupiter distance compare with the average Earth-Jupiter distance
   solar-system
Can we model gravitation as a repulsive force?
   gravity
How are interplanetary trajectories found?
   spacecraft space-flight
Meteorites from Mars?
   mars meteorite
Is there any way to judge whether a bolide might produce a meteorite?
   meteorite
What determines a progenitor's fate as a spiral or elliptical?
   galaxies star-formation angular-momentum
If you focus in on one image, is combining two telescopes (through optical interferometry)
   telescopes
Is a water world possible, and for how long could it be stable?
   planets solar-system sun atmosphere
Anti-Matter Black Holes
   black-holes astrophysics anti-matter
How do the day/night temperature variations of moons compare to those of their parent plan
   solar-system
Does the Earth help stabilize changes in the moon's obliquity as well?
   solar-system
Are meteorites igneous, sedimentary or metamorphic rocks?
   planets
What is the format for "local catalog" files used by JSkyCat?
   software fits-files
Do red galaxies have red star-lit skies?
   stars galaxies
Are there any Earth-Meteorites on Earth?
   meteorite
What is the irregularity of Uranus orbit caused by Neptune?
   orbit uranus
What are the most accurate ways to find the average distance between stars in the Milky Wa
   stars distance galaxy
Is angular resolution especially important when we just want to take the spectra of an Ear
   exoplanets
For resolving different objects, are there any alternative coefficients to the one used in
   telescopes
Are telescopes with a concave lens useful for astronomy?
   telescopes
How are galaxy filaments formed? And do they have any analogues in stellar formation?
   galaxies large-scale-structure
What are some molecules stable in outer space that are unstable under terrestrial conditio
   untagged
What distinguishes a moon from orbiting space debris? Or in other words, when is a satelli
   planets moons
Amateur Stargazing (30 degrees N)
   stargazing
What makes us think we can actually detect gravitational waves?
   untagged
How much energy does a super nova generate?
   astrophysics supernova estimation
How does the view of night sky change as the Sun orbits around the Milky Way?
   sun orbit milky-way
How far would you need to displace your eyes to get meaningful depth perception of the sta
   observation distance
How can Y-dwarf stars have such a low temperature?
   stars
What is the current evaluation of a sky map application for mobile devices?
   stars observation instrument
Why are our planets in the solar system all on the same disc/plane/layer?
   solar-system orbit planetary-motion
Are our telescopes capable of taking actual images of brown dwarfs?
   brown-dwarf
What conditions should an asteroid or comet impact need to meet in order to start an impac
   asteroid comet impact 
How do we determine what distant planets, stars etc are made of?
   planets stars spectroscopy
Assuming an observer is 50 light years away, in the plane of the solar system and observin
   exoplanets
What to show a beginner
   amateur beginner amateur-astronomy
Why is the measured distance to the Triangulum Galaxy much more uncertain than to the Andr
   distance observational-techniques
Curvature of the Universe imaginary?
   universe universal-expansion
Galaxies seen from Earth
   galaxies
What are the differences in using an eyepiece with a barlow instead of a shorter eyepiece?
   observation visual-astronomy
The collision of Phobos
   planets moons mars
Rainbow around Sun
   sun light
Why do we always see the same side of the Moon?
   earth the-moon
What are the known relationships between rotation of planets/moons and their distance to s
   astrophysics
Why are some galaxies flat?
   astrophysics angular-momentum spin galaxies
Near-Earth supernova
   earth supernova speculative
How will the luminosity of the current very near supernova Ia "PTF 11kly" develop in the n
   stars astrophotography supernova amateur-astronomy luminosity
What equipment is needed for equatorial drift scanning/TDI with a Dobsonian?
   telescopes astrophotography
What happens to the neighboring star of a type Ia supernova?
   stars supernova binary-systems
Are there certain alignments in planetary orbits that create interesting effects in the mo
   planets
How did the radiative flux of each gas giant planet change with respect to time (since the
   planets
Particular targets of high angular resolution infrared telescopes
   instrument infrared
Formula for Rotation Curves of Galaxies
   galaxies rotation
Can the "Milky Way" galaxy be seen by the naked eye in a clear sky?
   stars photography
If the Earth didn't rotate, how would a Foucault pendulum work?
   earth physics
Are there Trojan family or Hilda family satellites locked in Earth's orbit?
   astrophysics earth satellite
Is building your own reflector telescope worth it?
   telescopes
How much of the Earth would a spoonful of the Sun scorch?
   sun
On what planar regions are the Earth, Moon.. for that matter, all astronomical bodies, pla
   earth the-moon
Remnant of a supernova
   supernova
Creating a Star Map
   visual-astronomy
Balmer lines and their positions
   stars 
How long does it take to travel 36 light years with tolerable acceleration and deceleratio
   space-flight light-years
How to get started in Astronomy (UK based)
   telescopes astrophotography software beginner amateur-astronomy
What is the name of this galaxy in HCG7?
   galaxies
Computing period, semi-major axis of binary
   calculations
Is it easier to learn more about the seasonal changes in an exoplanet's atmosphere when th
   exoplanets
Phases of the moon video
   the-moon education
Axial Tilt and precession rate of exoplanets
   exoplanets
How to calculate how many degrees the Sun is from the horizon?
   sun time calculations
What percent of planets are in the position that they could be viewed edge-on from Earth? 
   exoplanets observational-techniques
Are there planets that do not rotate on their axis?
   planets rotation
How vacuous is intergalactic space?
   universe intergalactic-space 
Where to find information on the pulsar map written to Voyager's golden record?
   space-flight voyager pulsars
Could there be a body of water the size of a planet?
   water
Is water necessary for forming the sedimentary rocks found on Mars' surface?
   mars
What physical interactions actually make single stars leave their binary companions at for
   stars
Why can't Jupiter be seen over Thanksgiving break?
   jupiter
Why are most astronomy things spherical in the shape (like, the Sun, the Moon, the Earth, 
   astrophysics
Are planetary orbits measured from the Sun's surface or centre?
   orbit
What sort of propulsion would we require for interstellar travel?
   space-flight intergalactic-space
Photographs of galaxies many light years far from the Earth
   astrophotography
Celestron NexStar 6 SE vs. Orion XT8
   telescopes stars astrophotography
Fall/Winter Viewing
   telescopes stars stargazing
Contents page of Exoplanets book
   exoplanets
New Type of Type Ia supernova. Implications to Dark Energy measurement?
   supernova dark-energy
"Reverse engineering" of a horoscope?
   calculations
Why is it hard to write a computer program to detect patterns which planethunters is askin
   exoplanets variable-star computer
What is the minimum magnification needed for an instrument to see all the Messier objects?
   untagged
If neutrinos travel faster than light, how much lead time would we have over detecting sup
   supernova light particle-physics
Where to get hard historical and trend data related to reentry of satellites like UARS
   orbit satellite
Why don't stars in globular clusters all orbit in the same plane?
   stars
What demonstrations for a five-hour optical and radio astronomy workshop?
   amateur radio-astronomy
Tropical year is 27s/year off from Gregorian year?
   time
Simple JavaScript formula for where the Sun or Moon are overhead to within 1 mile?
   calculations
How do we know the temperature on the planets?
   planets spectroscopy
Telescope for 6 year old and dad new to astronomy
   telescopes astrophysics visual-astronomy amateur-astronomy
Density of stars near the center of the Milky Way
   galaxies
What is the extent of the universe?
   universe
Will Neptune change Pluto's orbit some day?
   planets orbit
Video of Earth spinning?
   earth
Name for celestial "Prime Meridian"?
   untagged
Can neutrino detectors tell what direction the neutrinos came from?
   untagged
What are the minimum telescope requirements to view a nice spiral galaxy?
   telescopes
Pleiades through a 15x 76 mm telescope
   telescopes stars
How could they tell things weigh a sixth of their "Earth weight" on the moon?
   planets gravity the-moon
What could this very dark planet be made of?
   extrasolar-planets
How much of sky can be seen on a typical night from a mid-latitude location?
   observing
Did physical models of galaxies come before they were actually observed?
   galaxies
Why do rockets need a cosmic ray detector?
   spacecraft
Where can I find information for how to create amateur radio telescope?
   amateur amateur-astronomy radio-astronomy
Parallax Cloud Displacement - Angular Distance from Geostationary Satellite
   observation distance satellite cloud
How fast is the Cosmic Microwave Background Radiation (CMBR) changing?
   cmb 
Which way do spiral galaxies rotate?
   galaxies rotation
Get time from sun Azimuth
   sun
Telescope "blue book"
   equipment
Is dark matter around the Milky Way spread in a spiral shape (or, in a different shape)?
   astrophysics cosmology milky-way galaxy
What happens when astronomical bodies made up of Dark Matter collapse or collide?
   astrophysics cosmology dark-matter
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Astronomy imports: 4 of 5

The following posts were migrated here from Astronomy. The original tags are listed below each link.

<sup><sub>Split among 5 answers due to length</sub></sup>

```
Stellar evolution simulation engine or software
   software star-formation simulation
Reverse Sun position algorithm?
   sun
Illumination calculations?
   physics
Formula for getting time of sunrise at a particular location?
   solar earth-science
Why Aren't Saturn's Rings Clumping into Moons?
   moons rings
How do you transform between theoretical Hertzsprung-Russell Diagrams and Colour-Magnitude
   stars color magnitude
Why isn't sunset time in sync with solstice?
   sunset solstice
Why is this radio telescope's reflector spherical and not parabolic?
   telescopes radio-astronomy
Atmospheric interference and ground based stellar observations
   spectroscopy
Why do clusters of stars eventually dissipate?
   gravity stars globular-clusters
Why does Jupiter emit more energy than it receives?
   planets gravity jupiter
Does Mercury have a balmy spot?
   mercury
Is it true that our solar system belongs to another galaxy which collides with the milky w
   galaxies 2012
What is a good introductory text to astronomy
   beginner
Creating/Downloading a large Galaxy Dataset
   galaxies education
What's the most accepted theory for Blue Stragglers These Days?
   stars globular-clusters blue-supergiants
Is there any way to anticipate exceptional Aurora Borealis viewing conditions?
   sun visual-astronomy
2012: Is there some astronomical event happening?
   planets
Pulsar beam radiant intensity distribution
   pulsars
How bright will an asteroid be?
   observation asteroid
Where can I find a list of when I can see something in the sky?
   visual-astronomy amateur-astronomy meteor-showers
Are there trends in the number of meteors in a shower year on year?
   meteor-showers
Is the CMB rest frame special? where does it come from?
   cmb
Transit of Mercury: how did he see it?
   sun mercury
Difference between baryonic, inertial and gravitational mass? (and relation to dark matter
   dark-matter mass
Where does the dust on the moon come from?
   the-moon
Use of advanced mathematics in astronomy, like topology, abstract algebra, or others
   astrophysics universe equipment
How do I find the time for Pleiades to be at Zenith today
   stars the-moon
How to concisely explain apparent retrograde motions of planets?
   planets visual-astronomy orbit retrograde-motion
Why did population III stars lack planets?
   stars
Best time of the year to see the star Alpha Centauri in Chile, Santiago
   stars visual-astronomy observational-techniques
Does anybody actually do astrometry in the 21st century?
   stars planets time observational-techniques instruments
Shadow of a Jovian moon over the Great Red Spot
   jupiter
What is the physical origin of scintillation?
   telescopes atmosphere seeing
Liquid Water in "mid-ice" on Europa. Mechanism?
   jupiter europa exo-geology
What would the universe look like if it started out without any irregularities?
   big-bang
Could a neutron star be active, fusioning neutrons into something more dense and releasing
   stars neutron-stars
The Sun as a gravitational lens
   gravity gravitation
Is the Apophis asteroid a concern?
   asteroid
Comet versus asteroids versus meteors
   asteroid comet meteorite
If we were to travel through space (sci-fi style), how close to the false-color images wou
   galaxies space-flight color
Do we have an idea about the amount of matter in the universe?
   universe dark-matter mass
Detecting dim objects
   astrophotography satellite
November 25th 2011 partial solar eclipse visibility from Christchurch, New Zealand
   observation eclipse observational-techniques
The Bahtinov focusing mask
   telescopes visual-astronomy reflector focus
Why are spacecraft made to "spin" after launch?
   exploration launch nasa
Code to sample from & integrate light of a cluster?
   astrophysics imf
Why doesn't a close comet like Elenin look like other, famous comets (Hale Bopp, Halley...
   observation comet
What are the facts that allow accepting the Oort cloud theory?
   solar-system observation theory oort-cloud
Did Penzias and Wilson use Wein's law (or data based on it) to determine the temperature o
   cmb
How plausible is a subsurface ocean on Pluto?
   water pluto
Why can there be fire in space while there is no oxygen?
   sun
What is the best evidence/theory about the first generation of stars
   stars big-bang star-formation
Why doesn't our solar system run into other solar systems over billions of years?
   solar-system gravity
How are exoplanets confirmed?
   exoplanets
What has theoretical physics gotten first?
   theory professional-astronomy string-theory
Is there any chance we could eventually observe the supernova of the first (Population III
   stars supernova big-bang
How is the Hanbury-Brown and Twiss effect used to measure the size of stars?
   distance instrument quantum-mechanics
How can we know, today, that there's something from 100 light-years from here?
   physics
How to explain the Moon halo phenomenon?
   the-moon
Universe is expanding at enormous speed
   astrophysics universal-expansion physics
Calculating the Suns vector and distance from the Earth at one time
   solar-system orbit calculations
Is there more mass in stars or interstellar medium?
   cosmology
How does space affect the human body (no space suit, no space craft)
   intergalactic-space
Best observing techniques for a Total Lunar Eclipse?
   the-moon eclipse
Lumped circuit model of Earth and Sun as a thermal system
   planets sun earth simulation weather
How many Pluto sized planetoids have been discovered?
   planets solar-system
Is it possible to look into the beginning of the Universe?
   big-bang
How long does it take for radio or light waves to travel from Earth to Jupiter, Saturn, Ur
   planets solar-system distance light
Is there an established standard for naming exoplanets?
   exoplanets names
Is There Reddening on Objects Other than the Moon Upon Entry into Earth's Umbra?
   the-moon orbit eclipse satellite
Why can't you escape a black hole?
   black-holes relativity
Polar ice deposits on the Moon - dispersed in permafrost loose rubble, or also massive/lay
   moon water instruments
Could there be more universes?
   universe big-bang time
How can Voyager 1 escape gravity of moons and planets?
   orbit gravity spacecraft voyager
Which direction before dawn to look for Comet Lovejoy (C/2011 W3)?
   observation comet
When do natural leap years occur, on years based on the northern winter solstice?
   orbit earth calculations spin
Light years and redshift from our point of view. How can we see it?
   big-bang universal-expansion
Is the moon a planet?
   earth moon satellite
What is the fate of the asteroid belt?
   solar-system asteroid asteroid-belt
Novice interested in buying a used telescope. What questions should I ask?
   telescopes amateur
Does a reference or classification standard for altitude classifications of geocentric orb
   orbit classification
Is there an Algorithm to find the time when the sun is X degrees above the horizon for a g
   sun
Recommended first accessories for starblast 4.5
   telescopes visual-astronomy equipment
How to measure the diameter of a star?
   stars
How does the winter solstice relate to the "longest night"
   earth solstice
Will the universe reach zero mass?
   cosmology
Where are the Voyagers going?
   voyager intergalactic-space interstellar-space
What happens to light that falls into a black hole?
   black-holes light singularity
How big (compared to our moon) would Saturn look from Titan's surface?
   planets saturn titan
How to care for a Dobsonian around the ocean?
   dobsonian corrosion maintenance
Should I be concerned about spot corrosion on a telescope's primary mirror?
   telescopes corrosion maintenance mirror
Does the moon affect human behaviour?
   the-moon
Why does the debris from comets and former comets hang around so long?
   meteor-showers
What's in my box?
   intergalactic-space interstellar-space
How can I understand Einstein Space?
   astrophysics
Quality loss when adding more components to a telescope?
   telescopes astrophotography focus
Gravity of a disc
   astrophysics gravity
How to locate the Orion Nebula?
   telescopes nebula
How much sky do we see at any one moment?
   meteor-showers eye-physiology
Determining cloud cover from observer to near the horizon
   telescopes weather observing
Is there a way to create an artificial solar eclipse?
   sun eclipse physics
Will the James Webb Space Telescope be able to capture something similar to, or better tha
   telescopes professional-astronomy deep-space space-telescope james-webb-telescope
Cassini: What information could be gained from the 2017 impact with Saturn?
   spacecraft rings saturn
The Moon during the day
   the-moon
Issues with Celestron 130 SLT and shaking
   telescopes astrophotography reflector
Looking for a resource that explains all colors and shapes of stars and galaxies
   galaxies color
Hartmann mask based collimation
   astrophotography equipment
How can the date of lunar eclipses be calculated by hand?
   eclipse moon
Sky-Watcher Skyhawk 1145P SynScan AZ GOTO
   telescopes
Does Celestia take the lunar orbit precession into account?
   orbit moon
Can a minimum ultimate tensile strength (UTS) for an asteroid be established based on its 
   asteroid rotation
Why doesn't helium start to fuse while there is still hydrogen fuel?
   stars physics
Confusing description of Orions belt, could someone clarify?
   observation
Interstellar bodies
   asteroid interstellar-space
If a hot Jupiter was not tidally locked, then are there any specific cases where its wind 
   exoplanets
Why don't any of the gas giants have moons of Earth's mass (or greater) that orbit them? I
   exoplanets
Raising Altitude by using Magnetic Torquer and Reaction Wheels
   orbit satellite
What is lighting up Space Shuttle Endeavour's main engines?
   unknown-object ssme
What proportion of a star's hydrogen is consumed in its life?
   stars astrophysics sun
sun-moon-earth anomaly
   the-moon
Are Uranus and Neptune too big for their location?
   planets solar-system
What is stopping us from stick building a space station?
   spacecraft
How bright are auroras (aurorae)?
   astrophotography aurora
Is it possible that I just saw Jupiter's moons?
   moons jupiter
Relation between isophotal radius and virial radius in spiral galaxies?
   galaxies
What telescope would I need to observe Mars's polar caps?
   telescopes mars
How to stabilize an unstable telescope?
   telescopes
How far into space does one have to travel to see the entire face of earth?
   earth spacecraft space-flight
Does the dark matter halo rotate with the galaxy?
   cosmology dark-matter galaxy
Automated telescope system
   telescopes astrophotography
How do we explain the phase change between high and low star formation rates?
   galaxies galaxy star-formation
Is it safe to observe the sun through binoculars with welding glass in front?
   sun observation solar
Why are there no images of faceted crystals outside of Earth?
   earth mars water
Does the sun cross over a given meridian line every day at the same time?
   sun
Why is 1 AU the distance between the Sun and the Earth?
   sun earth distance
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Astronomy imports: 5 of 5

The following posts were migrated here from Astronomy. The original tags are listed below each link.

<sup><sub>Split among 5 answers due to length</sub></sup>

```
Identifying objects, for dummies
   amateur-astronomy unknown-object
How big is the Solar System?
   solar-system
Do all the individual stars that we can see in the night sky belong to Milky Way?
   milky-way stargazing
What will we see between the CMB and the current oldest object seen?
   cmb
Have Sterling Engines Been Used In Outer Space?
   resources
How to adjust feather touch focuser for collimation?
   dobsonian collimation secondary-mirror focuser laser
Missing radio source coordinates in G/T measurement technique ITU-R S.733.2
   radio-astronomy
AGN accretion disk vs. torus
   galaxies
How to make a moondial?
   moon
Need help buying binoculars online for astronomy (10x50)
   telescopes beginner
Stability of moons around tidally locked exoplanets
   exoplanets
What is the orbital path of Omega Centauri?
   milky-way local-group
Biggest crater in the Solar System
   mars crater collisions
Was Aristarchos' method to compute Earth-Sun distance ever rediscovered in medieval or mod
   sun earth distance moon
How much detail can telescopes actually provide?
   telescopes optics
Emission line width units
   spectroscopy
Galaxies that are newer than our own one
   galaxies light-years
Why is there a limit to the intensity of cosmic rays at low energies?
   particle-physics
From Computational Astrophysics to Finance
   astrophysics
Why are there not many detectable supernovas?
   supernova stars galaxy
Sky-Watcher Skymax-127 (AZ) 127mm (5") f/1500 SynScan GO-TO Maksutov-Cassegrain Telescope
   telescopes
Why does Omega Centauri have a distinct chemical signature from the rest of the Milky Way?
   milky-way globular-clusters dwarf-galaxies metallicity
How is it that some nebulae are rotating and others are not?
   astrophysics physics nebula
Double image in binoculars
   binoculars
Is there such a thing as "North" in outerspace?
   intergalactic-space speculative
Have scientists been able to find an example of a possible White Hole?
   black-holes
What's the best way to start out with astrophotography on a tight budget?
   astrophotography beginner
Convert ECI coordinates to latitude/longitude?
   satellite calculations
How can I determine if my telescope mirror is parabolic?
   telescopes reflector
Computing Planetary Positions
   planets software
Existing photometry data of the open star cluster Cepheus OB3?
   stars
Why do we need the concept of dark energy to explain the expansion of the universe?
   big-bang universal-expansion dark-energy
What would happen to Earth if Saturn were to exit the Solar System?
   planets solar-system earth saturn
What makes a supermassive black hole move through space?
   black-holes deep-space
What is the weekly average of coronal mass ejections the sun sends out?
   sun coronal-mass-ejection
Is there any site/place which gives access to astronomical signals acquired from space?
   telescopes radio-astronomy
What is a Hot Flow Anomaly, and can we see the terrestrial ones?
   solar-wind magnetosphere
Is it possible to see satellites with the naked eye?
   satellite
Can CMEs disturb a planet orbit?
   sun orbit coronal-mass-ejection
Where will New Horizons go after sailing past Pluto?
   solar-system spacecraft kuiper-belt
Predicting solar storms?
   light solar-system solar-wind
Accuracy and assumptions in deriving the Tully-Fisher relation
   astrophysics galaxies distance
How to draw a star chart?
   stars
Can you damage your eyes viewing Venus?
   observation
May 20th Annular Eclipse - Duration from Vancouver?
   eclipse observing
What is behind the cosmological horizon barrier?
   astrophysics
Figuring out which moons of Jupiter I saw through my telescope
   telescopes moon jupiter
At what distance could you see andromeda with the naked eye?
   galaxies intergalactic-space
Falling into Saturn or Jupiter, would we pass through it until we hit the nucleus?
   planets
Can we see a spaceship falling into a black hole and entering the event horizon?
   black-holes
What is exactly the density of a black hole and how can it be calculated?
   black-holes
Impact location that created the moon
   earth moon formation collisions
Io - Turned inside out
   orbit jupiter moons io
Can we prove that the universe is finite or infinite?
   universe
Ring height stats?
   rings
Are we going to be able to travel trough space deforming the space-time?
   special-relativity
Is there any scientific evidence that demonstrates why time passes?
   time
Where does the light of the Big Bang come from?
   big-bang light pulsars deep-space
How can you calculate the exact position of the Earth taking into account the gravitationa
   planets
How do we know the masses of single stars?
   stars mass
What will happen if a gamma-ray burst hits the Earth?
   cosmology gamma-rays
Sky projections in sky view software
   visual-astronomy software
How can I visualize a gas giant?
   jupiter
Why does the homogeneity of the universe require inflation?
   big-bang
Why is Jupiter so sharply defined?
   astrophotography gravity jupiter
Black Hole Photon Sphere
   black-holes neutron-stars
Can't find anything in my scope
   telescopes beginner
How to correct flares and sharply focus on my telescope when viewing planets.
   telescopes planets focus
What are the best astronomy blogs and podcasts?
   resources
Can a neutron star compress until it's converted to a black hole?
   black-holes neutron-stars
Could there be a sort of "Molecular Destiny"?
   earth big-bang dark-matter anti-matter
Who has succeeded in demonstrating the Lense-Thirring effect?
   gravity rotation earth-science
Theoretically, can a black hole collapse until it gets smaller than its Schwarzschild radi
   black-holes schwarzschild-radius
Why doesn't the Earth leave you as soon as you escape it?
   orbit earth
How will a super massive black hole effect our galaxy?
   galaxies black-holes milky-way spin
Does the universe have a center?
   universe big-bang universal-expansion
What sort of equipment would I need to take a photo like this?
   astrophotography equipment
How to â€˜correctâ€™ reflected image on my telescope?
   telescopes reflector
Astronomy Experiments for Amateurs
   amateur-astronomy
What does velocity dispersion (sigma) reveal about a galaxy?
   black-holes
Andromeda/Milky Way collision: How, and how accurately, can a galaxy's lateral velocity be
   galaxies
Is there a correlation between the mass of a supermassive black hole and the mass of its h
   galaxies black-holes
Mass/light ratio of galaxies
   galaxies
Mass of Milky Way Supermassive Black Hole
   black-holes
SAO star catalog
   resources
What prevents stars in globular clusters from merging over time to form a black hole?
   globular-clusters
How to determine day/night based on latitude, longitude and a date/time?
   calculations solar
How do we know Dark Matter is non baryonic?
   dark-matter
Error analysis of flux from telescope-CCD setup (photometric calibration)
   telescopes astrophysics
Can I determine whether it is night at a location by calculating only the sun's elevation?
   sun calculations
Population I and II stars
   galaxies
How do I determine RA of my meridian at a given time, date and location?
   observation
What does Orion's Belt look like from the Equator?
   stars orbit earth
What is the position and orientation of the Earth as a function of time
   solar-system calculations
Why do the stars in the galaxy core move so fast?
   astrophysics
Do the stars photographed by a telescope even exist at present?
   astrophysics distance
Why did the WMAP mission last so much longer than Planck?
   cmb wmap planck
Can we see ALL of the observable universe?
   universe
What are the chances that a deadly asteroid will hit Earth in the next decade?
   orbit earth asteroid estimation impact
How much gas is in elliptical galaxies?
   galaxies
Why are jets not commonly found in spiral galaxies?
   galaxies
Why can't dark matter be black holes?
   black-holes dark-matter
Does gravity travel at the speed of light?
   gravity light
Can extraterrestials detect our messages?
   radio-astronomy astrobiology
What is this shadow of the Sun on the Moon?
   moon
Where can I find information on space navigation, and the people who pioneered it?
   spacecraft equipment space-flight exploration
How to calculate the amount of night time during a flight?
   time calculations
Why can I never see any stars in the night sky?
   stars observation
RA/dec to Alt/Az program or method
   calculations
Calculating distance to an asteroid on a given day
   distance asteroid
Are the Milky-Way solar systems depicted in Larry Nivens "Known Space" based on "real worl
   observation visual-astronomy milky-way intergalactic-space
Rocket needed to send 100 gram of mass to outer space?
   space-flight
What is actually meant by 'sun set' and 'sun rise' times, when taking into account the mir
   sun time sunset
Energy and Matter
   big-bang
Why are there more vertical takeoff than horizontal for spacecrafts?
   spacecraft space-flight
What's the reason for the seasons?
   sun earth weather
Why don't we see solar and lunar eclipses often?
   sun earth moon
Calculations of apparent magnitude
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Theoretical Physics imports: 1 of 3

The following posts were migrated here from Theoretical Physics. The original tags are listed below each link.

<sup><sub>Split among 3 answers due to length</sub></sup>

```
What is known about the classification of N=4 SCFTs with central charge 6?
   conformal-field-theory 
SuperHiggs Mechanism on different Backgrounds & Compactifications
   supersymmetry string-theory
Are possible gauge fields in a Lagrangian theory always determined by the structure of the
   math-ph gauge-theory symmetry quant-ph
models of higher Chern-Simons type
   quantum-field-theory gauge-theory
Renormalization Group for non-equilibrium
   quantum-field-theory cond-mat renormalization-group
Theoretical penetration limit for evanescent waves
   classical-electrodynamics uncertainty-principle optics
Applications of delay differential equations
   math-ph differential-equations
Mermin-Wagner theorem in the presence of hard-core interactions
   math-ph statistical-mechanics spin-model 
Technical naturalness of Yukawa couplings
   higgs standard-model
Do Gauge Theories (CFTs) Have Phase Transitions as the 't Hooft Coupling is Varied?
   conformal-field-theory adscft
Connections and applications of SLE in physics
   math-ph statistical-mechanics conformal-field-theory probability
Hypersingular Boundary Operator in Physics
   math-ph intuition
Status of local gauge invariance in axiomatic quantum field theory
   quantum-field-theory math-ph
What is the current state of research into $v$-representability?
   math-ph quant-ph chemical-physics
The Role of Rigor
   math-ph history-overview 
Onsager's Regression Hypothesis, Explained and Demonstrated
   math-ph statistical-mechanics
Extensions of DHR superselection theory to long range forces
   math-ph quantum-field-theory
What is the use of a Universal-NOT gate?
   quant-ph quantum-computing
An entropy of the Wigner function
   quant-ph uncertainty-principle entropy wigner-function
Sampling typical clusters between distant points in subcritical percolation
   statistical-mechanics simulation
Which is the coupling between the photon and the SU(2)xU(1) gauginos, before symmetry brea
   supersymmetry soft-question
Metric interpretation of self-adjoint extensions?
   quantum-mechanics non-commutative-geometry
Systematic approach to deriving equations of collective field theory to any order
   quantum-field-theory statistical-mechanics gauge-theory
Can the CPT theorem be valid if Lorentz invariance is only spontaneously broken?
   quantum-field-theory special-relativity
Counting complete sets of mutually unbiased bases composed of stabilizer states
   quant-ph quantum-mechanics quantum-computing group-theory
Where do theta functions and canonical Green functions appear in physics
   soft-question
What is the importance of studying degeneration on $M_g$
   soft-question
Other processes than formal power series expansions in quantum field theory calculations
   quantum-field-theory
Quasiparticles in Bohmian mechanics
   quantum-mechanics
How Exactly Does Linear Regge Trajectories Imply Stability?
   math-ph hep-th string-theory
Why Are Even and Odd Regge Trajectories Degenerate?
   hep-th string-theory
Fluctuations of an interface with hammock potential
   statistical-mechanics spin-model 
What are some critiques of Jaynes' approach to statistical mechanics?
   statistical-mechanics
BPS states : Mathematical definition
   quantum-field-theory hep-th string-theory supersymmetry
experimental bounds on spacetime torsion
   gravity
Principle behind fidelity balance in quantum cloning
   quant-ph quantum-mechanics quantum-computing
Orbits of maximally entangled mixed states
   quant-ph group-theory entanglement
Gauge invariance for electromagnetic potential observables in test function form
   quantum-field-theory reference-request
Quantum Field Theory from a mathematical point of view
   quantum-field-theory math-ph reference-request
Is there a theorem that says that QFT reduces to QM in a suitable limit? A theorem similar
   quantum-field-theory quantum-mechanics
Negative probabilities in quantum physics
   math-ph quant-ph probability wigner-function
List of known Seiberg-dual pairs of N=1 gauge theories
   quantum-field-theory supersymmetry
Topological twists of SUSY gauge theory
   hep-th supersymmetry gauge-theory
Connections of iterative solvers for large systems of equation in Physics?
   statistical-mechanics quantum-mechanics classical-electrodynamics hamiltonian-mechanics
Which QFTs were rigorously constructed?
   quantum-field-theory math-ph rigorous-qft
N=2 SSM without a Higgs
   supersymmetry standard-model
What methods are there to deal with quantum spatiotemporal chaos?
   quantum-field-theory
Which exact solutions of the classical Yang-Mills equations are known?
   gauge-theory classical-field-theory yang-mills-theory
What is a simple intuitive way to see the relation between imaginary time (periodic) and t
   quantum-field-theory statistical-mechanics
Graduate School for Theoretical Physics
   soft-question
Modern avatar of Englert's solution?
   hep-th supergravity
Super Lie-infinity algebra of closed superstring field theory?
   string-theory
How to write a paper in physics
   soft-question
Description of metal and aromatic interactions in protein ligand interacions
   chemical-physics
Miura transform for W-algebras of exceptional type
   hep-th
Relevance of SIC-POVMs to quantum information
   quantum-mechanics quantum-information quantum
What is the state-of-the-art on spacelike singularities in string theory?
   string-theory general-relativity gr-singularity
What proof techniques have failed for solving the SIC-POVM problem and what new insights h
   quantum-mechanics quantum-information
Majorana-like representation for mixed symmetric states?
   quantum-mechanics permutation-symmetric majorana-representation
Decoherence and measurement in NMR
   quantum-information quantum-control nmr quantum-measurement
Holographic Renormalization in non-AdS/non-CFT
   quantum-field-theory renormalization holography
Renormalization in string theory
   quantum-field-theory string-theory renormalization
Which are the simplest known contextual inequalities?
   quant-ph contextuality
What does Gribov's last paper tell about coloured states?
   gauge-theory
why no double counting of s- and t-channels in string theory?
   string-theory
Lorentz transformation in light cone coordinates in string theory
   string-theory
AGT conjecture and WZW model
   conformal-field-theory
Minimal strings and topological strings
   math-ph string-theory reference-request
Supersymmetric Nonrenormalization Theorems
   quantum-field-theory supersymmetry renormalization
On-shell symmetry from a path integral point of view
   quantum-field-theory supersymmetry
infinity of running couplings
   renormalization-group
Is the distinction between the PoincarÃ© group and other internal symmetry groups artificia
   quantum-field-theory gauge-theory
Quantum mechanics as a Markov process
   quantum-mechanics quant-ph reference-request
Length of publication cycle for peer-reviewed journals
   soft-question publishing
Phase diagram of simplified QCD
   quantum-field-theory quantum-chromodynamics thermal-qft
False vacuum in axiomatic QFT
   quantum-field-theory rigorous-qft
Quantum mechanical gravitational bound states
   quantum-mechanics gravity quantum-gravity
status of +4/3 scalar as explanation of $t\bar t$ asymmetry
   particle-physics hep-ph
Lorentz force in Dirac theory and its classical limit
   quantum-mechanics quantum
From Manifold to Manifold?
   math-ph general-relativity
Possible research implications of proof of John Cardy's a-theorem in QFT
   quantum-field-theory soft-question citation
Partition Functions in (A)dS/CFT
   adscft
Experimental test of the non-statisticality theorem?
   quantum-mechanics quant-ph quantum-foundations experimental-tests
"finite" QFTs and short-distance singularities and vanishing beta functions
   quantum-field-theory string-theory supersymmetry
Derivation of Eq. 7.12 in the review paper of Kraus
   hep-th adscft
Expectation values of interacting fields
   quantum-field-theory
examples of heterotic CFTs
   conformal-field-theory
Hilbert-Schmidt basis for many qubits - reference
   quantum-mechanics
Classic mass predictions from Left-Right models with discrete symmetries?
   particle-physics hep-ph mass
Geometric entropy vs entanglement entropy (dependent on curvature coupling parameter)
   black-hole entropy naming
What papers should everyone read?
   soft-question big-list
quantum causal structure
   quantum-foundations
How much of the Capelli-Itzykson-Zuber ADE-classification of su(2)-conformal field theorie
   conformal-field-theory
Spekkens Toy Model, Internal Comonoids
   quantum-foundations
causality and operationalism:from sets and functions to monads
   quantum-foundations
Examples of number theory showing up in physics
   math-ph quantum-computing quantum-foundations math
Simple question on the foundations of spin foam formalism
   quantum-gravity
What videos should everyone watch?
   soft-question reference-request
Massive excitations in Conformal Quantum Field Theory
   quantum-field-theory conformal-field-theory
Quantum statistics of branes
   string-theory branes topological-qft
How to interpret vacuum instability of Higgs potential
   quantum-field-theory higgs
Defining the ground state energy of a QFT
   quantum-field-theory
Derivatives of fluctuations about a condensate
   quantum-field-theory cond-mat
Measurement of Tangential Momentum Accomodation?
   molecular-dynamics
Convergence of quantum effective action to finite loop order
   quantum-field-theory perturbation-theory
On the Coulomb branch of N=2 supersymmetric gauge theory
   supersymmetry
The Schwinger model
   quantum-field-theory reference-request
Higgs boson and string theory
   string-theory supersymmetry particle-physics
Group of symmetries of Lagrange's equations
   hamiltonian-mechanics lagrangian-mechanics
"tmf(n) is the space of supersymmetric conformal field theories of central charge -n"
   reference-request conformal-field-theory
Mathematical Physics Book Recommendation
   book-recommendation
Renyi fractal dimension $D_q$ for non-trivial $q$
   statistical-mechanics entropy fractal
Dimensional Regularization Integral Formula
   quantum-field-theory
Quantum gravity at D = 3
   quantum-gravity
Simulation of QED
   reference-request standard-model
"gauge fixed world-sheet action"
   quantum-field-theory string-theory
Relativistic corrections to quantum mechanics of Coloumb potential
   quantum-field-theory quantum-mechanics quantum-electrodynamics
Is there precision experimental evidence for Furry's theorem -- that only even degree VEVs
   quantum-field-theory hep-th hep-ph
Consideration of static atomic displacements in electronic structure calculations
   cond-mat
Physics in high lepton chemical potential
   quantum-field-theory particle-physics thermal-qft
Is renormalization associated with a volume scale or with an energy-momentum and length sc
   renormalization
Topics in particle cosmology
   particle-physics cosmology
General Relativity research and QFT in curved spacetime
   quantum-field-theory general-relativity
Nuclear physics from perturbative QFT
   quantum-field-theory perturbation-theory nuclear-physics
Regularization of the Casimir effect
   quantum-field-theory regularization
Some questions on a version of the O'Raifeartaigh model
   quantum-field-theory supersymmetry
Information geometry of 1D Ising model in complex magnetic field regime
   statistical-mechanics
Analog Hawking radiation
   quantum-gravity black-hole
Uniqueness of the 5 string theories
   string-theory
String landscape in different dimensions
   string-theory string-landscape
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Theoretical Physics imports: 2 of 3

The following posts were migrated here from Theoretical Physics. The original tags are listed below each link.

<sup><sub>Split among 3 answers due to length</sub></sup>

```
Advanced topics in string theory
   string-theory soft-question
Derivation of the basic equation for Witten diagrams
   quantum-field-theory string-theory adscft quantum-gravity
Wilson Loops in Chern-Simons theory with non-compact gauge groups
   quantum-field-theory hep-th reference-request topological-qft
Readable books on advanced topics
   soft-question book-recommendation
Torsion and gauge invariant EM kinetic term
   gravity gauge-symmetry
Stability of the vacuum state of interacting quantum fields
   quantum-field-theory thermal-qft classical-thermodynamics
How to prove equivalence of RG flow of QFT coupling constant and diagrammatic resummation 
   quantum-field-theory renormalization-group
Modular invariance for higher genus
   quantum-field-theory conformal-field-theory
Pohlmeyer reduction of string theory for flat and AdS spaces
   string-theory adscft quantization
How can one build a multi-scale physics model of fluid flow phenomena?
   classical-thermodynamics simulation fluid-dynamics lattice-boltzmann
Values of SM parameters at one certain scale
   quantum-field-theory supersymmetry standard-model renormalization-group
POVMs that do not require enlargement of the Hilbert space
   quant-ph quantum-foundations
functional representations of free quantum fields
   quantum-field-theory reference-request
Time reversal symmetry and T^2 = -1
   quant-ph
Significance of massive states in string theory
   string-theory
Relativistic center of mass
   classical-field-theory special-relativity
Many body quantum states analyzed as probabilistic sequences
   quantum-mechanics reference-request quantum-information spin-model locc
Intuitive sketch of the correspondence of a string theory to its limiting quantum field th
   string-theory soft-question
Reduced density matrices for free fermions are thermal
   entanglement thermal-qft lattice-qft
random matrix ensembles from BMN model
   quantum-mechanics hep-th
Interesting topics to research in mathematical physics for undergraduates
   quantum-field-theory string-theory soft-question
Spectrum of a quantum relativistic "distance squared" operator
   quantum-mechanics special-relativity
String-theoretic significance of extended CFT
   string-theory conformal-field-theory
Different kinds of S-matrices?
   quantum-field-theory scattering
Matlab package: graphical calculus for quantum operations (esp. linear optics)
   quantum-information quantum-optics software linear-optics
Spatial and polarizing beam splitters in a graphical calculus
   quantum-information quantum
Colour decomposition of $n-$gluon tree amplitude
   quantum-field-theory yang-mills-theory particle-physics scattering quantum-chromodynamics
Thermodynamic limit "vs" the method of steepest descent
   quantum-field-theory math-ph statistical-mechanics cond-mat cond-mathÃ»stat-mech
Do bipartite spin glasses have simple relaxation dynamics?
   statistical-mechanics spin-model
Poisson structure on moduli space of CFTs
   string-theory conformal-field-theory
What is the upper-limit on intrinsic heating due to dark matter?
   particle-physics experimental-tests
Papers and preprints worth reading, Jan-midFeb 2012
   journal-club
Fourier Methods in General Relativity
   reference-request general-relativity
A solvable model for the finite rectangular potential well with a bump in the middle
   quantum-mechanics
Do thermodynamic quantities in CFT correspond to something different in AdS/CFT?
   conformal-field-theory adscft
Irrelevance of parastatistics for space dimension > 2
   quantum-mechanics
Quantum mechanics as classical field theory
   quantum-mechanics classical-field-theory
Discussions of the axioms of AQFT
   quantum-field-theory reference-request
Status of large-scale structure formation within cosmology today
   cosmology astrophysics
Mathematical rigorous introduction to solid state physics
   math-ph book-recommendation
Unitarity of S-matrix in QFT
   quantum-field-theory reference-request
Some questions about the BCFW reduction
   quantum-field-theory string-theory yang-mills-theory quantum-chromodynamics scattering
$(\mu,P,T)$ pseudo-ensemble: why is it not a proper thermodynamic ensemble?
   physicsÃ»ed-ph cond-mathÃ»stat-mech classical-thermodynamics
What are the justifying foundations of statistical mechanics without appealing to the ergo
   statistical-mechanics 
Continuum theory from lattice theory
   quantum-field-theory renormalization lattice-gauge-theory
Why isn't the Gear predictor-corrector algorithm for integration of the equations of motio
   integration molecular-dynamics 
Vassiliev Higher Spin Theory and Supersymmetry
   quantum-field-theory gravity supersymmetry hep-th gr-qc
Is there a Majorana-like representation for singlet states?
   quant-ph quantum-mechanics permutation-symmetric majorana-representation
Limitations in using FLEX as a DMFT solver
   quantum-field-theory perturbation-theory
Can symmetry generators be used for quantization?
   math-ph quantization group-theory hep-th
Significance of the hyperfinite $III_1$ factor for axiomatic quantum field theory
   quantum-field-theory math-ph
Quantum computing and quantum control
   quant-ph quantum-computing quantum-control
Physical interpretation of different selfadjoint extensions
   math-ph quant-ph quantum-mechanics hilbert-space functional-analysis
How Fundamental is Spin-Orbit Coupling to Topological Insulators?
   cond-mat
Does entropy measure extractable work?
   statistical-mechanics
Does 4D N = 3 supersymmetry exist?
   quantum-field-theory math-ph supersymmetry
Kerr Geometry, Separability and Twistors
   gravity gr-qc
ATLAS Higgs Interpretation
   higgs standard-model 
Instantons and Non Perturbative Amplitudes in Gravity
   quantum-field-theory gravity hep-th gr-qc
Why can't noncontextual ontological theories have stronger correlations than commutative t
   quantum-mechanics nonlocality contextuality
Bell polytopes with nontrivial symmetries
   quantum-mechanics nonlocality
Post-doc advice for a low publication grad student
   career-advice soft-question
Visualization of 1D spin chain wave fuction
   quantum-mechanics spin-model 
What do theoretical physicists need from computer scientists?
   computer-science soft-question
Applications of the Feynman-Vernon Influence Functional
   quantum-field-theory hep-th
What is a good introduction to integrable models in physics?
   book-recommendation 
Models of neutrinos consistent with OPERA's results
   hep-th 
Dual Pairs in Four Dimensions
   hep-th supersymmetry duality
6d Massive Gravity
   gravity reference-request 
Information Retrieval
   quant-ph gr-qc 
Which symmetric pure qudit states can be reached within local operations?
   quant-ph permutation-symmetric majorana-representation group-theory
Are lens spaces classified via a Weinberg angle?
   kaluza-klein compactification
Relationship between Weak Cosmic Censorship and Topological Censorship
   gravity gr-qc topology
Stabilizer formalism for symmetric spin-states?
   quant-ph quantum-computing
The derivation of the Belinfante-Rosenfeld tensor
   quantum-field-theory classical-field-theory special-relativity
Sub and super multiplicativity of norms for understanding non-locality
   quantum-mechanics nonlocality norms entanglement
Phase Transition in the Ising Model with Non-Uniform Magnetic Field
   statistical-mechanics spin-model phase-transition
Canonical averages in a Fermi gas aka generalized Fermi-Dirac distribution
   statistical-mechanics reference-request cond-mathÃ»stat-mech 
Uniqueness of supersymmetric heterotic string theory
   hep-th string-theory
Choice and identification of vacuums in AdS/CFT
   string-theory
Cosmic bubble collision
   gr-qc cosmology 
Random Walk Randomly Reflected
   probability 
Calculating correlation functions of exponentials of fields
   quantum-field-theory
Instanton Moduli Space with a Surface Operator
   hep-th
Any use for $F_4$ in hep-th?
   hep-th symmetry
Covariant derivatives
   hep-th
Why isn't there heterotic holographic QCD?
   quantum-field-theory string-theory
Is string theory local?
   math-ph string-theory
Sympletic structure of General Relativity
   general-relativity hamiltonian-mechanics 
Is ghost-number a physical reality/observable?
   quantum-field-theory yang-mills-theory 
Geometric Langlands as a partially defined topological field theory
   quantum-field-theory hep-th
which letter to use for a CFT?
   conformal-field-theory
realization of: CFT generating fuction = AdS partition function
   hep-th string-theory gauge-theory adscft
Physical interpretation to the category of CFTs
   hep-th
Chern-Simons theory
   quantum-field-theory math-ph gauge-theory
Does the complex 3-sphere have a complex structure modulus?
   math-ph string-theory
direct sum of anyons?
   quantum-mechanics quantum-computing
Local Fermionic Symmetry
   hep-th supersymmetry
Scaling solutions in context of Denef - Moore
   math-ph string-theory supersymmetry
Are there rigorous constructions of the path integral for lattice QFT on an infinite latti
   quantum-field-theory math-ph rigorous-qft lattice-qft
Generalized Complex Geometry and Theoretical Physics
   math-ph string-theory supersymmetry
Why does charge conservation due to gauge symmetry only hold on-shell?
   classical-field-theory gauge-symmetry
Do Killing spinors know global information?
   quantum-field-theory hep-th
Is there a background independent closed string field theory?
   string-theory string-field-theory
KÃ¤hler potential vs full effective potential
   quantum-field-theory hep-th supersymmetry
Edge theory of FQHE - Unable to produce Green's function from anticommutation relations an
   quantum-field-theory cond-mathÃ»stat-mech
Linearizing Quantum Operators
   quantum-mechanics optics
What makes background gauge field quantization work?
   quantum-field-theory yang-mills-theory
Rigorous security proof for Wiesner's quantum money?
   quantum-mechanics quantum-information quantum-computing
A resource theory of quantum discord?
   entanglement quantum-information quantum-discord
Classic Literature in Quantum Gravity?
   reference-request quantum-gravity
What is the Holevo-Schumacher-Westmoreland capacity of a Pauli channel?
   quantum-information
Characters of $\widehat{\mathfrak{su}}(2)_k$ and WZW coset construction
   math-ph reference-request conformal-field-theory
How to prove quantum N=4 Super-Yang-Mills is superconformal?
   supersymmetry gauge-theory yang-mills-theory
What evidence do we have for S-duality in N=4 Super-Yang-Mills?
   supersymmetry yang-mills-theory duality lattice-qft lattice-gauge-theory
Are there stable string theory vacua with non-minimal cosmological constant?
   string-theory cosmology string-cosmology string-landscape
Literature on fractal properties of quasicrystals
   math-ph cond-mat quasicrystals
Explicit construction for unitary extensions of CPTP maps?
   quantum-mechanics quantum-information
Normalization of the Chern-Simons level in SO(N) gauge theory
   gauge-theory topology
State of Matrix Product States
   quant-ph quantum-information
Twistors in Curved Spacetime
   hep-th gr-qc twistors
What is the significance of the branch cut in renormalization group logarithms?
   quantum-field-theory renormalization
Global symmetry in string theory
   string-theory black-hole
Which CFTs have AdS/CFT duals?
   string-theory conformal-field-theory adscft
What Shannon channel capacity bound is associated to two coupled spins?
   quantum-information quantum-control
Geometric quantization of identical particles
   quantum-mechanics
Allowed states vis-a-vis allowed dynamics in generalized probabilistic theories (GPTs)
   quant-ph quantum-information nonlocality
Scherk-Schwarz and other compactifications?
   string-theory compactification
Quivers in String Theory
   quantum-field-theory math-ph string-theory
Some questions about the spectral function
   quantum-field-theory
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Theoretical Physics imports: 3 of 3

The following posts were migrated here from Theoretical Physics. The original tags are listed below each link.

<sup><sub>Split among 3 answers due to length</sub></sup>

```
Master Equations and Operator Sum Form
   quant-ph quantum-information
Accurate quantum state estimation via "Keeping the experimentalist honest"
   quant-ph quantum-information quantum-estimation
Operator norm directly from phase space representation of photonic quantum operator
   quantum-field-theory quantum-information optics wigner-function norms
CHSH violation and entanglement of quantum states
   quantum-information nonlocality entanglement
Which arguments for $m_u \approx 0$ are still in the market?
   particle-physics hep-ph
what compactifications of the Poincare group have been studied?
   compactification poincare-group
Rigorous proof of Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization
   math-ph quantum-mechanics
How does one geometrically quantize the Bloch equations?
   quantum-mechanics spin-model molecular-dynamics
Convexity -- reference request
   reference-request quantum
Is this a simple Lie algebra?
   math-ph particle-physics
Pauli-Villars regularisation breaks supersymmetry. How to see that?
   supersymmetry
Tree level QFT and classical fields/particles
   quantum-field-theory scattering classical-limit
Charged black holes in equilibrium
   general-relativity black-hole einstein-maxwell
Rigorous justification for rotating wave approximation
   quantum-mechanics quant-ph quantum-optics
Superconformal Multiplet Calculus in 6D
   hep-th supergravity
Optimality of the CHSH strategy
   quantum-mechanics entanglement history-overview
Conformal QFTs for D > 2
   quantum-field-theory conformal-field-theory
Numerical Analysis of Elliptic PDEs
   reference-request differential-equations
A question from Ticcati's red QFT textbook.
   quantum-field-theory quantum
Uniqueness of eigenvector representation in a complete set of compatible observables
   quantum-mechanics
Does Kaluza-Klein theory successfully unify GR and EM? Why can't it be extended to the Sta
   kaluza-klein
Virasoro constraints in quantization of the Polyakov action
   string-theory quantization
Higgs Field - Is its discovery truly "around the corner"? 
   higgs standard-model
Physical interpretation of superstrings
   string-theory
Matrix geometry for F-strings
   string-theory branes
Interplay between the cosmological constant and "microscopic" properties of string vacua
   string-theory string-landscape
Status of the little hierarchy problem
   higgs mssm
Asymptoticity of Pertubative Expansion of QFT
   quantum-field-theory
AdS/CFT at D = 3
   string-theory conformal-field-theory adscft
Depolarizing threshold for CSS codes
   quantum-information quantum-error-correction
In what sense are loop diagrams quantum corrections?
   quantum-field-theory
What is a "free" non-Abelian Yang-Mill's theory?
   quantum-field-theory gauge-theory yang-mills-theory gauge-symmetry
Where does the hidden supersymmetric sector of the MSSM come from?
   supersymmetry mssm
How does a geodesic equation on an n-manifold deal with singularities?
   gauge-theory black-hole gr-singularity
Wilson/Polyakov loops in Weinberg's QFT books
   quantum-field-theory reference-request gauge-theory soft-question yang-mills-theory
Applications of Geometric Topology to Theoretical Physics
   reference-request soft-question topological-qft
More general invariance of the action functional
   symmetry analytical-mechanics
Lagrangian for Euler Equations in general relativity
   general-relativity
General parameters of the stress energy tensor in local inertial frame
   general-relativity
References for phase-transitions in supersymmetric field theory
   quantum-field-theory string-theory supersymmetry reference-request phase-transition
Boundary conditions / uniqueness of the propagators / Green's functions
   quantum-field-theory classical-electrodynamics
Source term of the Einstein field equation
   soft-question general-relativity
An odd relation with the epsilon/delta invariant tensors of SO(3)
   quantum-field-theory group-theory
Some questions about Wilson loops
   quantum-field-theory yang-mills-theory
Do any entanglement measures for mixed states exist that use only single site correlation 
   spin-model entanglement
Solution to the Schrodinger equation for periodically time dependent Hamiltonians
   quantum-mechanics quant-ph simulation
Why is there no theta-angle (topological term) for the weak interactions?
   quantum-field-theory standard-model
Random bond Ising model and computational efficiency
   statistical-mechanics spin-model
Deviation of the effective potential between a quark and an anti-quark
   quantum-field-theory yang-mills-theory
Introduction to neutron star physics
   reference-request astrophysics neutron-stars introduction
What are some ways to (approximately) symbolically diagonalize Hamiltonian operator?
   quantum-mechanics quantum-optics
What Hermitian operators can be observables?
   quantum-mechanics reference-request quantum-measurement hilbert-space
Can the concurrence be calculated in terms of the entanglement of formation?
   quantum-information entanglement
Constructing a Hamiltonian (as a polynomial of $q_i$ and $p_i$) from its spectrum
   quantum-mechanics quant-ph
Constructing a CP map with some decaying property
   quant-ph quantum-information
Quantum memories: What are they?
   quantum-information quantum-computing quantum-optics
Feynman rules with helicity states.
   quantum-field-theory quantum-chromodynamics
Representation on Hilbert space of the product of two symmetry transformations
   quantum-mechanics symmetry
A nice overview (and maybe derivation) of the PoincarÃ© transformations of the Vector Spher
   reference-request poincare-group spherical-harmonics vector-spherical-harmonic
Unknown quantum state with promise of classical data
   quantum-mechanics quant-ph quantum-information
Kramer's-Kronig relations for the electron Self-Energy Î£
   quantum-field-theory
Renormalization of the R-charge?
   quantum-field-theory string-theory supersymmetry
The difference between projection operators and field operators in QFT?
   quantum-field-theory reference-request
Measure of Lee-Yang zeros
   statistical-mechanics
Analyticity and Causality in Relativity
   reference-request general-relativity special-relativity
Instantons and Borel Resummation
   renormalization instanton borel-resummation
Is there a recognised standard for typesetting quantum mechanical operators?
   soft-question
Tip of a spreading wave-packet: asymptotics beyond all orders of a saddle point expansion
   quantum-mechanics math-ph
Some more questions about the BCFW reduction
   quantum-field-theory yang-mills-theory quantum-chromodynamics scattering
Magnetic monopole and electromagnetic field quantization procedure
   quantum-electrodynamics
Question from Schutz's
   general-relativity special-relativity
Entanglement and conservation
   quantum-mechanics quantum-information
Is the universe a quantum computer - is light speed barrier a computational constraint
   quantum-mechanics quantum-information quantum-computing special-relativity
Entanglement in time
   quantum-mechanics entanglement
Krauss operators for random unitary
   quantum
shape of the state space under different tensor products
   quantum-foundations nonlocality
Equivalence of definitions of ADM Mass
   general-relativity mass
Monte Carlo integration over space of quantum states
   quantum-mechanics quantum-information probability integration
Multiqubit state tomography by performing measurement in the same basis
   quantum-mechanics state-tomography
Functional relations for Kochen-Specker proofs
   reference-request quantum-information contextuality
Low-energy gluodynamics as a string
   string-theory yang-mills qcd
Gauge invariance and the form of the Rarita-Schwinger action
   quantum-field-theory gauge-theory
A certain gluon scattering amplitude
   quantum-field-theory yang-mills-theory quantum-chromodynamics scattering
Why aren't the spin-3/2 fields in the (3/2,0)+(0,3/2) representation?
   quantum-field-theory
Gauge invariant scalar potentials
   quantum-field-theory gauge-theory gauge-symmetry
What is the connection between extra dimensions in Kaluza-Klein type theories and those in
   string-theory kaluza-klein
Spectrum of Free Strings
   string-theory
$\pm$ (light-cone?) notation in supersymmetry
   quantum-field-theory string-theory supersymmetry
Gravitating sigma models
   math-ph gravity book-recommendation
Time Evolution of a Manifold Embedding
   reference-request gauge-theory quantum-gravity manifolds
Heuristics for definitions of open and closed quantum dynamics
   quantum-mechanics quantum-optics
Asymptotic Completeness, generalized free fields, and the relationship of thermodynamics w
   quantum-field-theory wightman-fields
States diagonal in the tensor product of Bell states.
   reference-request quantum-information
Does it make sense to speak of amplitudes of finite closed boundaries in QFT?
   quantum-field-theory quantum-foundations
From vertex function to anomalous dimension
   quantum-field-theory phase-transition
About the definition/motivation/properties of the twisted chiral superfield in ${\cal N}=2</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quantum-field-theory string-theory supersymmetry
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27231/the-paper-by-fateev-and-zamolodchikov">The Paper by Fateev and Zamolodchikov</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;reference-request citation
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27738/geometric-picture-behind-quantum-expanders">Geometric picture behind quantum expanders</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quantum-information
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27183/could-motives-aid-in-the-study-of-the-navier-stokes-equations">Could motives aid in the study of the Navier-Stokes equations?</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quantum-field-theory renormalization non-commutative-geometry fluid-dynamics
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27220/why-when-can-the-gauge-superfield-and-or-chiral-superfield-kinetic-term-in-2-2">Why/When can the gauge superfield and/or chiral superfield kinetic term in $(2,2)$ SUSY be</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quantum-field-theory string-theory supersymmetry phase-transition
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27728/what-is-the-physical-difference-between-states-and-unital-completely-positive-ma">What is the physical difference between states and unital completely positive maps?</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quantum-mechanics quantum-information intuition
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27019/is-the-lagrangian-of-a-quantum-field-really-a-functional">Is the Lagrangian of a quantum field really a functional?</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quantum-field-theory hep-th functional-analysis
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27503/reference-request-susskind-glogower-original-paper">Reference request: Susskind-Glogower original paper</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;reference-request quantum-optics
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27433/looking-for-description-of-helstroms-measurement">Looking for description of Helstrom's measurement</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;reference-request quantum-information quantum-computing
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27539/qed-as-a-wightman-theory-of-observable-fields-with-a-collision-theory">QED as a Wightman theory of observable fields?  With a collision theory?</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quantum-field-theory
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27697/matrix-field-theory">matrix field theory</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quantum-field-theory functional-analysis
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27656/comparison-of-different-ab-initio-codes">Comparison of different ab-initio codes</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quantum-mechanics ab-initio-methods
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27248/advice-on-doing-physics-under-the-umbrella-of-mathematics-and-the-converse">Advice on doing physics under the umbrella of mathematics and the converse</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quantum-field-theory string-theory math-ph soft-question math
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27577/analytic-continuation-of-imaginary-time-greens-function-in-the-time-domain">Analytic continuation of imaginary time Greens function in the time domain</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quantum-field-theory cond-mat
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27781/partial-trace-with-sparse-matrices">partial trace with sparse matrices</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quantum-mechanics quantum-information quantum-computing simulation
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27587/higgs-mass-and-the-hierarchy-problem">Higgs mass and the hierarchy problem</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quantum-field-theory renormalization
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27163/fitting-free-qfts-into-the-haag-kastler-algebraic-formulation">fitting free QFTs into the Haag-Kastler algebraic formulation</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quantum-field-theory
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26932/what-is-a-hilbert-space-filter">What is a Hilbert space filter?</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quantum-mechanics quantum-information quantum-key-distribution
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27753/baryon-asymmetry">Baryon asymmetry</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;cosmology
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26979/poincare-symmetry-in-qft">Poincare Symmetry in QFT</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quantum-field-theory poincare-group
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27609/precise-definition-of-moduli-space">precise definition of "moduli space"</a><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quantum-field-theory
<a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27734/information-conservation-during-quantum-measurement-in-psi-epistemic-interpre">Information conservation during quantum measurement in $\psi$-epistemic interpretations
   quantum-foundations
instantons, anomalies, and 1-loop effects
   quantum-field-theory
Convert state Vectors to Bloch Sphere angles
   quantum-computing
```